# Show or Hide html content with java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show or hide html with java script `if (condition)`
Want to be able hide html when users use for example Firefox and show content when they use another browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

// In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Chrome";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Safari";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Firefox";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < 
          (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
{
 browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
 if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
  browserName = navigator.appName;
 }
}
// trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
 fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
 majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
}
 
if( browserName == "Chrome")
 document.write("What should i put at this line to hide test div?"); 
    
else
 document.write("Access Denied!,what should i put at this line to hide test div?"); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "test">
    <p>test div</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want show or hide content with if condition.I use this code to prevent opening my website in common browsers instead of my VB browser which is designed for my website.

Answer (score 0):

you may do that like this in jquery:

```
if( condition ){
   $( "#test" ).hide();
}else{
   $( "#test" ).show();
}
```

In case you want to do it with JavaScript you may do it like this:

```
if( condition ){
    document.getElementById("test").style.display="none";
}else{
    document.getElementById("test").style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: I added some extra information on how to do it with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the css:

```
.hidden { visibility:hidden; }
```

Based on the `if` statement:

```
a = document.getElementById('test')
a.className = a.className + ' hidden'
```

Of course none of your code will work is javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display="none";
```

This will hide the element with id test.

And of course it is to be executed in the *if-condition* part where you want the *div* tag to be hidden.